# powershell if statements strange behavior

Tags: powershell

So here's a kind of a silly problem. Can someone explain how this makes sense? I don't really know what else to ask. Why would the if statement change the value of the variable in it?

```
PS C:\Users\HD2> $format = 6

PS C:\Users\HD2> $format
6

PS C:\Users\HD2> if($format = 1){write-host "woo"}
woo

PS C:\Users\HD2> $format
1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In powershell, the `=` operator is used to assign values to a variable. To do comparison, use the `-eq` operator.

Comment: Haha wow that is slightly misleading. Thank you for the answer, I was going crazy. I couldn't figure out how the if statement was assigning values in the ().

Comment: I don't know about misleading. It is right there in the docs.